# Agent based modeling for Supply Chain Management

Tags: simulation

I am a final year student of Computer System Engineering.My FYP is Agent Based Modeling for Supply Chain Management. I don't know how to start it or which software should I use. Repast? Netlogo? Anylogic?
Please guide me how to proceed with my project.

Comment: You should talk to your project advisor for guidance on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this question is opinion-based, I was part of a project whose objective was to compare exactly the softwares you mentioned here: Repast, Netlogo and AnyLogic. What I did in this study was to create AnyLogic models. Someone else was creating the models in Netlogo and Repast.

There is no paper with the conclusions yet, but the person who did this study told me that AnyLogic was better in terms of easy to use and scalability than the others and Repast has the steepest learning curve. Nevertheless for small scale projects, AnyLogic and Netlogo are equally suited so it doesn't matter which one you choose.

Nevertheless, remember that AnyLogic on its free version allows you to use only 10 agents, which is a lot, but if your project is really big and you want everything for free, you may encounter a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

As a platform that allows to work with agents that include in the same platform: editing code, show the area of simulation and generate graphics. I think Netlogo platform is suitable for this reason. you can also link it with other programming languages like python and R.